# How to embed HTML code from WP Coder plugin (or other) into Main Index Template of the theme

Tags: plugins, customization, theme-customizer

I want to add some custom HTML code on the home page of my school's website. I managed to do this by adding the HTML code into the Main Index Template (index.php) file of the theme, however the code is a bit messy and I would like to embed it from other file. I'm already using WP Coder, however when I try to add the [WP-Coder id="4"] part into the index.php file instead of showing the code as it should be it just shows this as a text and doesn't work.

Is there other way to link the Main Index Template page with WP Coder or other similar plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `do_shortcode()` function which allows the execution of shortcodes the same way that they run when used in the standard content areas.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[WP-Coder id="4"]' ); ?>
```

If you need to get more complex you can read all about it [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/).

Comment: Thanks!! It works as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have used WP coder, I am still using this plugin. Earlier coding working properly but you can't create new one, as it is closed on 1st March - 2024 . My bad luck, trying alternate but couldn't find it. I try in my site:
https://mysuccessstartup.win/

If you see my site, Look very weird now.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/270302)